# add new routes to a resource without the added param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I would like to add a url to my comments route so I can call "post_comments_latest_path". I added something like 'get "comments/latest" => "comments#latest", :as => "latest"' but the route adds and the :commend_id to the path that is not needed. Any suggestions?

```
  resources :posts, :except => [:index] do
    resources :comments, :except => [:index, :show] do
        post "replies" => "comments#create_reply", :as => "create_reply"
        get "replies/new" => "comments#new_reply", :as => "new_reply"        
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
resources :posts, :except => [:index] do
  resources :comments, :except => [:index, :show] do
    post "replies" => "comments#create_reply", :as => "create_rely"
    get "replies/new" => "comments#new_reply", :as => "new_reply"
    get "latest", :on => "collection"
  end 
end
```

A **Member** route is one that links to a specific resource; requires an `id`.
A **Collection** route is one that links to a resource collection; does not require an `id`.

See the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was a bit confused with the collection.